# Asp.net MVC3 Seprate Authentication for admin area vs fronted

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, forms-authentication, asp.net-mvc-areas

I created a MVC3 website with an area named "admin" I use attribute on admin controllers to secure it and it works fine.but if an admin user gets to the fronted he should remain not logged in for that part of the site. He should have to be able to login in with another username into fronted.
How can i handle it?

Comment: simplest way would be to have a separate admin *site*, so each has its own authentication.

Comment: Thanks Andrew,But i think it should there be a better way.maybe use authenticate parameters or cookies or ..

Answer (score 1):

You could use roles. So define an `admin` role that you would specify when using the `Authorize` attribute on your admin area controllers and then define another role that will be used for the Authorize attribute on the frontend controllers:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "admin")]
```

Comment: Actually i use roles to authorize admin now.But this is not the problem.I want to my public section of website (fronted) be available for all (even not logined user) and also only public user could login frontend not admin however i can check authentication for public roles vs admin.the problem is when an admin user just logged in in admin area refer to fronted ,he remained login in fronted too! but he should not to be.he should be refered to public login page and login with different user name or he be known still not-loggined user for the fronted .

Comment: @user1110074, you decorate the public facing part of your site with `[Authorize(Roles = "frontend")]`. Now you simply remove all admin users the `frontend` role.